# ElasticSearch: How to disable allocation on a specific shard?

Tags: elasticsearch

My index currently has 5 shards all with data. Suppose I want to temporarily prevent any more data in a specific shard. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: This is a good question. No need to worry about downvotes. Downvoters will downvote for no reason :)

Comment: "Allocation" has very specific meaning in elasticsearch - it's the process of assigning (allocating) shards to nodes. What you are asking about is disabling indexing on a specific shard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, whether you can directly specify certain shards for your data to be stored to. But, while starting out, you can specify [_routing](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html#_required) values which will determine which shard will your data get stored into. Through this, you can indirectly govern elasticsearch to store your data in specific shard. For example, consider this mapping:

```
{
"comment" : {
    "_routing" : {
        "required" : true,
        "path" : "blog.post_id"
    }
}
```

}

The above code will obtain the hash of the _routing path that is provided to it, and depending on the hash value, it will choose the shard that it will get stored into. So, ultimately, all the comments of the particular post will be stored in the same shard.

The reason why people choose custom routing over the normal one i.e the reason why normally, we would want or data to be stored in specific shard is to increase the performance of the search query. You can specify the routing values which shard will perform your search.

I am not sure why you want your data to be stored in certain shards only.

[Here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/customizing-your-document-routing/) is a nice blog that explains why you want your data to be stored in specific shards, and how custom routing will help you in achieving that.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I want to allocate to 1 shard because I created the index with 5 shards for future scaling issues. Right now I just need 1 shard, so if all the documents get distributed across all 5 shards in the same node, this will affect query performance. So right now I want all docs to go to shard 1, so I can just query shard 1. When shard 1 is full, I'll make everything to shard 2, and query just 2 shards, etc. If ElasticSearch let me add extra shards for free in the future, then this wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: So I tried your solution, and routing seems to be ignored in the Bulk API. Have you experienced this? It works when I index a single document, and search but not BULK :*(

Comment: Update: I figured it out, I need to put routing in the actual payload, not in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

This is old question, but it is still very relevant today and I came to this post when I had a similar case where I have to allocate a document to a particular shard, not random or primary.

You can achieve this by `_routing` field of Elasticsearch by calculating a shard number with the given [formula](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html) by Elasticsearch:

```
shard_num = hash(_routing) % num_primary_shards
```

Let's say you would like to not allocate a document to shard number 2 and you have to give the routing name when the shard number is not 2 when the modulus is taken from its hash and number of the shard. For this you have to find a routing name, to explain in code, I will give an example in Java to find a shard number with a particular routing name:

```
String routing = "routingName11";
final int numberOfShard = 30;
final int shard = routing.hashCode() % numberOfShard;
System.out.println("Routing: " + routing + " - shard number: " + shard);
```

Output:

```
Routing: routingName11 - shard number: -25
```

You have to make sure that a routing name that you provide in the indexing does not lead to generation of that particular shard number. Like above the modulus of `routingName11` and 30 is 25 and that is a shard number. In this case, you do have to worry because an indexing document will not live in the shard number 2.

As a full example, I would like to demonstrate indexing with a routing name:

Let's say we create "**course**" index and set routing required:

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/course
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 30
    },
    "mappings": {
        "_routing": {
           "required": true 
        }
    }
}
```

Then you index a document like this:

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/course_index/_doc/1?routing=tenant0&refresh=true
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Data Security course in Lidl",
    "description": "The course teaches our core Data Security measurements here in Lidle. As new regulations are out, ....",
    "text": "Text of the couse goes here",
    "created_date": 152625632,
    "last_date": 152625632,
    "expiration_date": null,
    "domain_id": 10,
    "language_id": 2
}
```

In our case, we have a multi-tenant software where about 100 tenants (organizations) share the same index in Elasticsearch, and we had to make sure data security that one tenant can never see data from other tenants. The solution that we came to create an index for all tenants with 100 shards and dedicate one shard for each tenant by finding a routing name for each tenant. As you can see in the index mapping example above, the routing is set to "required"  and whenever you send CRUD operations to Elasticsearch, you have to define a routing otherwise Elasticsearch will throw `routing_missing_exception`